# GWT DataGrid Disable Mouse Hover Selection

Tags: gwt

I am trying to override the behaviour of the DataGrid automatically selecting a row when the mouse hovers over a row. I've tried to override the onBrowseEvent but since this is a final method in GWT I wasn't able to do this.

Has anyone had any luck with this and could point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
myTable.setSkipRowHoverStyleUpdate(true);
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, so thanks. What I needed really was setSkipRowHoverCheck(true) but I wasn't entirely clear in the question. Neither of these exist in GWT 2.4 but were only implemented in 2.5 apparently